# Change the layout of the search results?

Tags: magento-1.7, catalogsearch

Currently the search results page is in the 2coloums-left but I want to make it centred just to display the results, I tried editing the catalogsearch.xml of the theme file and the Settemplate tag, but no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: can you post the layout xml snippet you've used? Also try to add it to the `local.xml` in your template folder to make sure it's not overwritten

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add the change of the template to your local.xml

```
<catalogsearch_result_index translate="label">
    <label>Quick Search Form</label>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</catalogsearch_result_index>
```

Comment: I'm bit confused, where do I find the local.xml file? I went through the theme folder but it didn't contain one.

Comment: You have to create one. inside of the theme/layout folder. it is loaded automatically.

Comment: I just tried but no luck yet.

Comment: If you have a virgin local.xml be sure to add the XML header and the layout root element.